# C++: Reference/pointer to member variable as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, reference, member-variables

To start, I have something like this:

```
class Test {
    std::vector<int> a, b;
    void caller(...) { callee(...); }
    void callee(...) { /* Do stuff with 'a' */ }
}
```

What I wanted is to have a function that does exactly the same as `callee`  but for vector `b`. To do this there are two obvious solutions:

- Pass vector `a` or `b` as argument. However, `callee` is a recursive function that can go for hundreds of calls, and passing the vectors as arguments would just be unnecessary overhead.
- Copy the function `callee` and use vector `b`, which would be the best alternative, despite the fact that `callee` is quite a long function and I would have a lot of duplicate code.

Out of curiosity, I went looking for the templates part and I noticed that  can be used for

> lvalue reference type
>
> pointer type
>
> pointer to member type

So I tried to do this:

```
class Test {
    std::vector<int> a, b;
    void caller(...) { callee<a>(...); }
    template <std::vector<int> &x> void callee(...) { /* Do stuff with 'x' */ }
}
```

but I get

> error: use of ‘this’ in a constant expression

Is there any way to achieve this either with a reference or a pointer?

By the way, what I want can be seen as a function-scoped `#define`

Comment: "and passing the vectors as arguments would just be unnecessary overhead" I don't believe that you will even notice the "overhead" when you pass the vector by reference or pointer.

Comment: Well, yeah. But I would much rather opt for the second solution and not have any overhead at all.

Comment: If you want to use a template like that restrictively, you'd want to do `template <class T>` and wherever you use the type, accept a `T&` - if you specifically need to prevent it being used for say, `std::vector<char>` then use `std::enable_if` for a non-match.

Comment: Even I agree that passing as a parameter will not cause overhead question is still really interesting I didn't know we can pass variable as template arguments like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays and even tuples, but no love for good old pointers-to-members ?

```
class Test {
    std::vector<int> a, b;

    void caller(/*...*/) { callee<&Test::a>(/*...*/); }

    template <std::vector<int> Test::*vec>
    void callee(/*...*/) { /* Do stuff with `(this->*vec)` */ }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use a reference to a data member as a template argument: templates are compile-time, and the value of `this` is not known until runtime. In other words, you'd need a separate instantiation (separate binary code) for each *runtime object* of type `Test`.

What you *can* do is replace `a` and `b` with an array, and templatise `callee` by index into this array:

```
class Test {
    std::array<std::vector<int>, 2> ab;
    void caller(...) { callee<0>(...); }
    template <size_t idx>
    void callee(...) { /* Do stuff with 'ab[idx]' */ }
}
```

This way, you get only two instantiations of `callee` (one for `0` and one for `1`), with the indexing done (or at least doable) at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a facade:

```
class Test {
    std::vector<int> a, b;
    void caller_a(...) { callee(a); }
    void caller_b(...) { callee(b); }
    void callee(std::vector<int> &a_or_b, ...) {
    }
}
```

`callee()` will refer to its parameter, which will be passed in as one or the other class member.

Comment: That is what I mentioned in the first bullet solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the same logic as @Angew's answer, you could also use std::tuple, and it's quite interesting as with tuple you can also use different kind of containers in your callee function :

```
class Test {
    std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::list<int> > ab;
    void caller(...) { callee<0>(...); }
    template <size_t idx>
    void callee(...) { 
    ...
    auto aIt = std::get<idx>(ab).begin(); // gets either the vector or the list depending on template value
    ...
    }
}
```