# Is it possible to return a member variable of a class specified by a template function?

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointer-to-member, function-templates

I am trying to generalize a function for a game engine I am writing to simplify the shader loading process.

Anyway, the difficulty arises in my attempts to templating the function. I attempted to adapt the solution found in [this stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401650/c-reference-pointer-to-member-variable-as-template-parameter), and resulted in various versions of the following code without any ideal solutions:

```
template<typename T, typename U, U T::* x>
U testFunc(T& t)
{ 
    // Simplification of the extremely generalized function;
    // I want to return/utilize member variable x of input t
    return x;
}

struct testS1 { int a = 100; };
struct testS2 { bool b = true; };

testS1 tS1;
testS2 tS2;

// would ideally return 100
int c = testFunc<testS1, int, &testS1::a>(tS1);

// would ideally return true 
bool d = testFunc<testS2, bool, &testS2::b>(tS2);
```

Running the program gives the following error:

```
Severity: Error
Line: 46
Code: C2440
Description: 'return': cannot convert from 'int testS1::* ' to 'U'
```

I understand that the returned value `x` is not the same type as `U` because `int testS1::*` is not the same type as `int`.

However, I do not understand what syntax I would use to return the member variable `x` of type `U` from the struct `T`.

The real structs behind the placeholders `testS1` and `testS2` are very different from each other, so I would like to avoid using a base class/struct if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer has already provided the syntax for [accessing the pointer to the member data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/pointer-to-class-data-member). In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) using [abbreviated function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template), you could do it, less verbosely the same

```
template<auto  x>
constexpr auto testFunc(auto const& t)
{
    return t.*x;
}
```

Now you call with less explicate template arguments

```
int c = testFunc<&testS1::a>(tS1);
bool d = testFunc<&testS2::b>(tS2);
// ...
```

[See a demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nrMjP8x8M)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what Pepijn answered with. What if I wanted to return an std::vector? Such that the call-line is `std::vector<int> testVec = testFunc<&testS1::a>(tS1);` and the testFunc becomes something like `template<typename T, auto x> constexpr auto testFunc(auto const& srcVec) { std::vector<T>dstVec(srcVec.size()); std::transfer(srcVec.begin(), srcVec.end(), dstVec.begin(), [](auto const& mSrc){ return mSrc.*x; }); return dstVec; }` would it be possible to simplify it down to the single input template function, or no because of the internal std::vector?

Comment: @ModernEraCaveman Yes, of course with a help of helper trait: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YGb83o3E3

Comment: You're a wizard, JeJo! Helper traits look like complete magic because idk how they work, but it works lol. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Take my upvote. In my hurry I missed this better solution. @ModernEraCaveman I won't mind this answer to get the checkmark ;)

Comment: On it
I was struggling to decide on giving them the checkmark since `auto` may not work in every use case, but you've made that decision easy to make. Nonetheless, I appreciate your speed in providing a workable solution!

Answer (score 4):

```
template<class T, class U, U T::*x>
U testFunc(T& t)
{
    return t.*x;
}
```

You simply need to dereference `x` to get a `U`.

Comment: You are my hero <3

I tried 'return *x;' so idk why 'return t.*x;' never occurred to me! Thank you so much.